# Processar informações de um json em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api

Estou trabalhando com o Flowxo fazendo um BOT para telegram. Nele, preciso processar algumas informações diretos de uma API no formato json. Consigo incluir no processo um código em JavaScript.

O processo funciona mais ou menos assim:

Usuario envia uma mensagem > HTTP Request Webhook > Envio uma mensagem ao usuário

Ao enviar a mensagem ao usuário preciso que seja colocado como atributo o que o usuário enviou ao bot. Por exemplo:

```
HTTP_Request.data__{{mensagem do usuario}}
```

Eu precisaria de um código que pegasse o "Data" dessa API, sendo que existem vários (nesse caso o usuário manda qual ele quer), processasse no código somente a informação que condiz com o que o usuário quer e manda o resultado de volta ao usuário.

Um dos problemas é que até o laço de repetição nesse Flow XO é limitado. Somente 20 vezes, portanto, acredito que teria que trabalhar com Array ou vetor, não sei...

PS: Não sei nada de JavaScript

Comment: Unico momento que preciso de um código em JavaScript é aí. Preciso ler as informações vindas de uma flow, processar e armazenar a que eu quero em um array e me dar a resposta. Só preciso de um norte ou alguem disposto a me ajudar pra conseguir fazer. Qualquer informação é útil desde que esteja com a mente aberta.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta um exemplo das informações vindas e o que você quer fazer com elas.